# Jet taking off from an aircraft carrier

Tags: forces

If a jet takes off from an aircraft carrier, should it not already be traveling at the speed of the carrier.  Also, does the jet require more energy to get off the carrier than from a stationary base?

Comment: You forgot to add in the wind itself. Also, the current of the ocean complicates the ship's velocity vector.  In many ocean conditions, I expect that the wind will be faster than the ship itself.

Comment: assuming wind speed is 0 and ship moving at a constant speed of course

Comment: @Jody Add all of your assumptions to your question proper. It will make it easier on folks if they don't have to sift through the comments.

Comment: @Jody: Yup, you're right, it'll be traveling at the speed of the carrier when it starts. However, the carrier is probably (?) slow compared to the takeoff speed of the jet, so it'll be a small effect.

Comment: Technically, the question simply relates to the velocity or speed of the jet in relation to the carrier and the energy required to get off the carrier.  It is redundant to calculate wind speed, tidal currents, etc. if that wasn't posed in the question.

Comment: As a matter of operational doctrine it is preferred to turn carriers into the wind and make way to launch.

Answer (score 1):

Speed is always the speed of one thing relative to another. For example, by speed of the carrier, you mean the speed of the carrier through the ocean.

If the wind speed is 0, this means the wind is still compared to the ocean. But someone on the moving carrier will feel a headwind.

For a jet to fly, the wind must flow over its wings. It doesn't matter if the wind blows or the jet moves.

Suppose the motion of the carrier through the ocean and the wind over the ocean add up to a strong headwind. Then the jet doesn't need to speed up as much to fly.

Suppose they add up to a tailwind. The jet would have to fly faster than usual to take off.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the velocity of the carrier adds to the additional velocity provided by the jet's own engines to make the jet's actual velocity relative to the earth.

For flying parameters of a aircraft, however, it is the velocity relative to the air arround it that matters.  A plane needs to be moving forwards thru the air to produce the lift needed for it to stay up.  This is exactly why aircraft carriers are preferably aimed into the wind when planes take off from its deck.  The velocity of the aircraft carrier relative to the air is a "free" head start the plane gets in reaching its minimum velocity to fly.